# What results from combining monopotassium phosphate, magnesium sulfate and calcium nitrate?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, safety

If I mix monopotassium phosphate, magnesium sulfate, and calcium nitrate together in aqueous solution, what chemicals will result?

Are these safe to combine (i.e. any toxic gases, etc.)?

I thought [this answer](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091014231235AAhb7jw) about just magnesium sulfate and calcium nitrate was insightful.

Comment: Based on the linked question, I assume you're talking about mixing them in aqueous solution?

Comment: You won't get any gases.